# Как изменить компонент при скролле vue js?

Tags: vue.js

[Мой код](https://codepen.io/kerf/pen/YQRoxM), написал решение, но на magic mouse проскакивает к последнему компоненту.

```
var A = { template: '<div class="a">Страница A</div>' }
var B = { template: '<div class="b">Страница B</div>' }
var C = { template: '<div class="b">Страница C</div>' }
var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', redirect: '/a' },
    { path: '/a', component: A },
    { path: '/b', component: B },
    { path: '/c', component: C }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  methods: {
    onWheel(event) {
      var delta = event.deltaY
      var routes = this.$router.options.routes
      var idx = routes.findIndex(item => item.path === this.$route.path)
      if (delta > 0 && idx < routes.length - 1) {           
        this.$router.push(routes[idx+1])            
      } 
      if (delta < 0 && idx > 0) {
        this.$router.push(routes[idx-1])     
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Подскажите как решить или может есть библиотека для смены компонентов? Хочу чтобы работало так, только не приезжали слайды, а уезжал контент и приезжал новый.

Comment: ссылка на codepen у вас неверная

Comment: Да сори. https://codepen.io/kerf/pen/YQRoxM

Comment: Ссылку вставьте в вопрос и спороводите его кодом для воспроизведения проблемы.